# Parallel loading of Files/URIs to external table in greenplum

Tags: greenplum, external-tables

If I specify multiple URIs for `LOCATION` in `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` in greenplum database, will it load the files in parallel? or does it make no difference loading the whole file versus splitting the files into multiple files and loading them instead?
[Official Doc](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43220/ref_guide/sql_commands/CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple gpfdist instance will load/unload data on defined location in parallel fashion. That is the real use of greenplum db

Answer (score 1):

Files are loaded in sequence, per command.
If you specify multiple files, eg: gpfdist://data/file_*

Then all of those files will be loaded in sequence, concurrently by all the segments.

You can achieve faster concurrent loading by splitting the files over multiple gpfdist instances.

eg: 
gpfdist://data/file_part_1* 
gpfdist://data/file_part_2*

For a video example, see:
https://youtu.be/QqzUhTgWPZg?t=4m48s

Comment: Does it mean that if i run gpfdist service on 4 different folders and distribute my files to those 4 folders, those files will load in parallel?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.